# Painting columns in a multirow table

Tags: colors, latex, tabular

I am trying to define and paint a multirow table by columns using the following:

```
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx} 

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\definecolor{lf}{RGB}{204,153,255} % lila fuerte
\definecolor{ns}{RGB}{255,225,193} % naranja suave

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{clf}{>{\columncolor{lf}}c}
\newcolumntype{cns}{>{\columncolor{ns}}c}

\begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|clf|cns|clf|cns|}
    \hline
    Verbo & CD & Suma binaria & Core \\
    \hline
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Buy} & 0 & 1 & \multirow{2}{*}{1}\\
    \cline{2-3} & 1 & 0 & \\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Sell} & 0 & 0 & \multirow{2}{*}{0}\\
    \cline{2-3} & 1 & 1 & \\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Exchange} & 0 & 0 & \multirow{2}{*}{0}\\
    \cline{2-3} & 1 & 1 & \\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Use} & 0 & 0 & \multirow{2}{*}{0}\\
    \cline{2-3} & 1 & 1 & \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Tabla_1}
    \label{tab:core_contextual}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

But it returned te followng error in all code lines:

> Package array Error: Empty preamble: `l' used.

First I tried to put the `\newcolumntype{}` out of the `\begin{document}` but it seems wrong and now, idk what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A couple or problems:

- missing document class
- `_` is only allowed in math mode, if you want to use it in normal text, you have to escape it
- use single letter column names
- to avoid overlapping with the background colour, place your `\multirow` in the second row and merge upwards with `{-2}`

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx} 

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\definecolor{lf}{RGB}{204,153,255} % lila fuerte
\definecolor{ns}{RGB}{255,225,193} % naranja suave

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{u}{>{\columncolor{lf}}c}
\newcolumntype{k}{>{\columncolor{ns}}c}

\begin{document}



\begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|u|k|u|k|}
    \hline
    Verbo & CD & Suma binaria & Core \\
    \hline
    \hline
     & 0 & 1 &\\
    \cline{2-3} \multirow{-2}{*}{Buy} & 1 & 0 &  \multirow{-2}{*}{1}\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Tabla 1}
    \label{tab:core_contextual}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]